# Interior of the complement of a set

Tags: general-topology

How do I show that $(A^{c})^{\circ} \subset ((A^{\circ})^{c})^{\circ}$?

I am aware that this is the same as asking to show $ext(A) \subset ext(A^{\circ})$.

Answer (score 4):

$A^{\circ}\subset A$, hence upon taking complements, we have to invert, and we get $A^{C}\subset (A^{\circ})^{C} $ . Now considering the interiors, which preserves the inclusion order, we get $(A^{c})^{\circ} \subset ((A^{\circ})^{c})^{\circ}$.

Comment: How would you go about proving that the converse is not true? I have been given some guidance but have not able to make any progress towards the answer.

Comment: Consider $A$ to be the Cantor Set, then $A^{c} $ is an open set  which misses the uncountably many points of the Cantor set. However, $(A^{\circ})^{c})^{\circ}$ is the entire unit interval, which shows the converse cannot be true. (or for that matter, choose A to be any finite point collection of $\mathbb{R}$)